# Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in pcategories.php

Tags: codeigniter

How to fix this error message?

Can you help?

Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-www\companygiondaci\application\views\pcategories.php on line 56

Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-www\companygiondaci\application\views\pcategories.php on line 56

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Error
Message: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
Filename: views/pcategories.php

views/pcategories.php

```html
<div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12">
                    
                    <button type="button" class="add" onclick="location.href='<?php echo site_url('cpages/addparentctg'); ?>';">ADD PARENT CATEGORIES</button> 
                    
                    <div class="widget-box">
                        <div class="widget-title"><h5>Parent Categories</h5></div>
                        <div class="widget-content">
                        
                        <table border="0" style="width: 100%; height: 90px;">
                            <tr>
                                <td>PARENT NAME</td>
                                <td>DESCRIPTION</td>
                                <td>EDIT</td>
                                <td>DELETE</td>    
                            </td>
                            
                            <?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
                            
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $post['ctgparent_name']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $post['ctgparent_description']; ?></td>
                                <td><button type="button" class="edit" onclick="location.href='<?php echo site_url('cpages/editparentctg/'.$post->ctgp_no); ?>';">EDIT</button></td>
                                <td><button type="button" class="delete" onclick="location.href='<?php echo site_url('cpages/editparentctg/'.$post->ctgp_no); ?>';">DELETE</button></td>    
                            </td>    
                                                                                    
                            <?php endforeach; ?>    
                            
                        </table>            
                        </div>
                    </div>                    
                </div>
            </div>
```

controllers/Cpages.php

```html
public function pcategories() { 
    
            
        $data['posts'] = $this->Mpages->call_parentctg();

        //$data['ctgparent_name'] = $this->Mpages->call_parentctg();
        //$data['ctgparent_description'] = "Second";//$this->Mpages->retrieve_parentctg();
        
        $this->load->view('pcategories', $data); 
        
    }
```

```html
models/Mpages.php

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter returns result rows as objects, not arrays. 
So you need to access it using -> . Like instead of $post['ctgparent_name']; use $post->ctgparent_name.

Comment: Or you can convert your object into array eg $result = json_decode($json, true);

Answer (score 0):

This happens if you're trying to access properties of an object with `$object['property']` notation instead you have to use `$object->property`.In your case you're doing `$post['ctgparent_name']` and `echo $post['ctgparent_description']` and you can change those to `$post->ctgparent_name` and `$post->ctgparent_description` respectively.

There is another solution if you're using codeigniter active records to fetch data from the database (as I suspect you do). If you're using `$query->result()` method, this will give you an object. You can use `$query->result_array()` instead so you now have an array of results you can play with `$array['whatever']` notation.

Further, if you're using `PDO` or `mysqli` there are methods to get database result sets as an array. Refer the official documentation [PDO result array](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php),  [Mysql result array](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) or [Mysql associative array](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php).